# Passing 'this' from a form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a function that checks all elements of a certain type when a form is submitted, and prevent submission if one of the elements doesn't validate. I've used jQuery to find all forms in the page, and attach this function to the 'onsubmit' event of them.

The problem with this, is as the function checks **all** elements of a certain type, it will prevent forms from being submitted if there are invalid elements in another form, even though it isn't being submitted so they don't matter.

To remedy this, I've altered my function to check all elements of a certain type to accept a parameter of a form, and then only validate elements in that form. So far so good.

However, when the function is attached to all the forms on the page with jQuery, how can I specify the parameter of the form?

Here's the jQuery code at the moment:

```
jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    return CheckElements();
});
```

I need to pass the current form, either as an ID or object. Something like:

```
jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    return CheckElements(SOME WAY OF PASSING THE FORM);
});
```

Is this possible, and if so how can it be performed?

Comment: Hum, have you tried with `this`?

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yeah I've just always preferred to write it that way..I'm not sure why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass it as an argument: `return CheckElements(this);`

Your `CheckElements` function can then look e.g. like this:

```
function CheckElements(form) {
    $(':input', form).each(function() { /*do something*/ });
}
```

If you prefer to have `this` point to the form in the function you can use `return CheckElements.call(this);` to invoke your function; then you not need the parameter and inside the function you can do e.g. `$(':input', this)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    return CheckElements(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) I marked the other one as read as it's more verbose but yours would also work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to first assign a class or id to a form. for eg.

```
<div class='error' style="display:none; color:red;">the entry by you was invalid</div>
<form action="XXXX" method="XXXX" class='myForm'>
<!-- lets say you have following fields -->
name : <input type = 'text' name = 'name' class = 'field1'>
age : <input type = 'text' name = 'age' class = 'field2'>
<input type = 'submit' id='submit_btn'>
</form>
```

Now instead of calling function onSubmit you can do following to call your JQuery function

```
$(function(){
$("#submit_btn").click(function(){
var msg = checkElement();// your function must return false on error
if(msg == FALSE)
{
$('.error').show(); //create a div with style dispay:none which contains error message to show on error
}
else
{
var field1 = $('.field1').attr('value');//fetching the field1 content
var field2 = $('.field2').attr('value');//fetching the field2 content

//submit via ajax
$.ajax({
url: 'relative path to the file eg. file.php',
dta: 'f1='+field1+'&f2='+field2,//placeyour own data here
type: 'get or post',
success:function()
{
alert('done');//perform your action
}
});
return false;
}
});
});
```

hope this helps you